# Defaulting fields - Java-JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am reading from one db table and writing same data to another db table.
Now if the date fields in the source do not have any data (`null`) then when it gets written to the destination table - the same fields get defaulted to a date "1/1/1900".
I have not set this default value anywhere in my program. Not sure why it is happening.

Any idea how can I prevent that instead of checking each field for `null` values and setting it to a different value?

I am using Eclipse and SQL Server database.

Thanks.

Comment: Post the code you're using where you validate this `null` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is that the default value for the date columns are actually set to '1/1/1900'. If so , remove this default using SQLs ALTER TABLE. Syntax for SQL Server is:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ALTER COLUMN DateColumn1 DROP DEFAULT
```

**Update:** As it looks like this date is the out-of-the-box default, try setting:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ALTER COLUMN DateColumn1 DATETIME NULL
```

Some important notes here:

1. Backup your database before you start altering tables(!)
2. Use the the same datatype (e.g. DATETIME) in your ALTER command.

Comment: no. that field is not getting defaulted at all. already checked that.

Comment: @jill Reimeus means about the configuration of the table in SQL Server, not in your specific Java application.

Comment: yes. I checked the DDLs for the tables in SQL Server. i do followingin my code: String date1 = resultset.getString("Date1"); If (resultset.wasNull(){ set date1 = ""; }

Comment: Would recommend posting a new question with more of your code. :)